# What is going on in this log file?

Tags: security

I'm a server n00b, running a website off a Windows 2012 r2 server.  My website has slowed to a crawl, so I started looking through some log files in C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles and I started seeing a bunch of this:

2018-03-05 05:21:34 **MyIPAddress** GET /Dates.aspx U=878 80 - 162.158.79.99 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+bingbot/2.0;++http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm) - 200 0 1236 86200

2018-03-05 05:25:50 **MyIPAddress** GET /Dates.aspx U=895 80 - 172.69.70.69 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+Googlebot/2.1;++http://www.google.com/bot.html) - 200 0 1236 85069

2018-03-05 05:27:17 **MyIPAddress** GET /robots.txt - 80 - 141.101.97.124 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+SeznamBot/3.2;++http://napoveda.seznam.cz/en/seznambot-intro/) - 404 0 2 657

2018-03-05 05:27:36 **MyIPAddress** GET /ImageCSharpThumb.aspx FileName=855_20180206121628_2012-09-02+KS+Knuckleheads.jpg 80 - 172.68.215.128 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+SeznamBot/3.2;++http://napoveda.seznam.cz/en/seznambot-intro/) - 200 0 0 666

2018-03-05 05:28:35 **MyIPAddress** GET /Dates.aspx U=269 80 - 141.101.97.121 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+SeznamBot/3.2;++http://napoveda.seznam.cz/en/seznambot-intro/) - 200 0 64 45704

2018-03-05 05:37:47 **MyIPAddress** GET /robots.txt - 80 - 172.69.70.213 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+Googlebot/2.1;++http://www.google.com/bot.html) - 404 0 2 2460

2018-03-05 05:37:51 **MyIPAddress** GET /ads.txt - 80 - 172.69.69.80 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+Googlebot/2.1;++http://www.google.com/bot.html) - 404 0 2 503

2018-03-05 05:38:03 **MyIPAddress** GET /favicon.ico - 80 - 108.162.215.128 Mozilla/5.0+(Macintosh;+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10_7_0)+AppleWebKit/535.11+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/17.0.963.56+Safari/535.11 - 304 0 0 6620

2018-03-05 05:38:20 **MyIPAddress** GET /ogPipe.aspx name=http://www.dongtaiwang.com/ 80 - 172.68.211.224 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/55.0.2883.87+Safari/537.36 - 404 0 1236 10958

Can someone tell me what the hackers are trying to do, and if there's any way to defend it?  My server is completely unusable, my IP told me whatever is going on is using 100% of my allotted upload bandwidth.

Comment: In this log file only search bots are showed. It's not strange behaviour of typical web server. Please, open system activity monitor and find that process which is using greatest upload bandwidth. P.S. Please, put log file output in code block.

Comment: First, [fix your IIS logging configuration](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170666-How-do-I-correct-visitor-IP-with-Microsoft-IIS-).